# Hide div after slidetoggle 5s

Tags: jquery, html, toggle

I use slideToggle to open and hide div as you see below.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.btnopencart').click(function() {
        $('#shoppingCart').slideToggle( "fast", function() {

        });
    });
});
```

But I want to set 5s for display #shoppingCart and of course it can toggle again although it is 'display:none' or 'display:block'

Thank you very much.

Comment: You want the slideToggle to take 5 second to complete, or you want a delay of 5 seconds before it begins?

Comment: Actually, I want a delay of 5 seconds before it begins or when it is shown in 5s, it will be auto hide. If users click many times, it continues toggle.Is it possible?

Comment: @MinhAnh Did you check out my answer?

Comment: Hi Praveen. Thank for you quick answer and it is so helpful but If users click many times (less 5s), it continues toggle.Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`.delay()`](https://api.jquery.com/delay/) and `$(this)`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.btnopencart').click(function() {
    $('#shoppingCart').slideToggle( "fast", function() {
      $(this).delay(5000).slideToggle("fast");
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Hi @Praveen Kumar. Thank you very much for your answer but I want a delay of 5 seconds before it begins. If users click many times (less 5s), it continues toggle.Is it possible?

Comment: @MinhAnh Yes, you can do. You need to add a `.stop(true, true)` before the `.delay`. Check if that works?

Comment: Hi Praveen. I added but It opens and close immediately?

Comment: @MinhAnh Give me a sec.

Comment: @MinhAnh Works fine for me here: http://jsbin.com/robiwivoka. Click on open, wait 5 seconds, it automatically closes. Can you please check again?

Comment: Hi Praveen. It is working with your code above? Is possible to continue toggle if users click it and start again delaying in 5 seconds?

Comment: @MinhAnh Yes, I didn't change any code. Just copied and pasted it there, it works perfectly. Click on the edit with JSBin or http://jsbin.com/robiwivoka/edit?html,css,js,output to see it works.

Comment: I know and I tested for few minutes ago :) but I asked new question about :"if users click it(toggle) and it will start again delaying in 5 seconds?".

Comment: @MinhAnh Yes. It will.

Comment: I mean if it is in the 4th sec and people toggle it, it is still possible and start again. You spent a lot time for me. Thank you very much. :).

Comment: @MinhAnh Yes, it does it that way. It resets the timer.

Comment: Yes. exact. If possible :).

Comment: @MinhAnh Ha ha... No if possible. It does it. `:)`

Comment: @MinhAnh I don't understand. The current code does it already. `:)`

Comment: :D haha. Maybe my english is not good.  As you can see, when it is shown (from 1st sec -> 4th sec ), we cannot click to hide it?

Comment: @MinhAnh I guess you didn't say that. But yea, it does it.